# DrawText doesn't add ellipsis to the end of a text in MFC

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a simple MFC application in which I'm trying to add ellipsis to the end of a string.

Here's my code:

```
void CMFCApplication1Dlg::OnPaint()
{
     if (IsIconic())
     {
         CPaintDC dc(this); // device context for painting

         SendMessage(WM_ICONERASEBKGND, reinterpret_cast<WPARAM>(dc.GetSafeHdc()), 0);

         // Center icon in client rectangle
         int cxIcon = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXICON);
         int cyIcon = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYICON);
         CRect rect;
         GetClientRect(&rect);
         int x = (rect.Width() - cxIcon + 1) / 2;
         int y = (rect.Height() - cyIcon + 1) / 2;

         // Draw the icon
         dc.DrawIcon(x, y, m_hIcon);
     }
     else
     {
         CPaintDC dc(this); // device context for painting

         CRect rect;
         rect.top = 0;
         rect.bottom = 100;
         rect.left = 0;
         rect.right = 100;
         dc.DrawText(_T("This is a very very long text that should span accross multiple lines and have elipsis at the end"), -1, &rect, DT_WORDBREAK | DT_MODIFYSTRING | DT_END_ELLIPSIS);

         CDialogEx::OnPaint();
     }
 }
```

This is what I get:

[image: output]

I was expecting ellipsis to be added to the end of the string. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have `DT_MODIFYSTRING` but are sending a const string. Try sending a modifiable string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As noted by @JonnyMoop `DT_MODIFYSTRING` can't be used with `DT_END_ELLIPSIS` for constant string. You can just remove `DT_MODIFYSTRING` in this case.

`DT_WORDBREAK` and `DT_END_ELLIPSIS` don't work well together. Try adding `DT_EDITCONTROL`

Also, `CDialogEx::OnPaint();` is a call to `CPaintDC dc(this);` so don't use them both.

```
void CMFCApplication1Dlg::OnPaint()
{
    CPaintDC dc(this);

    CRect rect;
    rect.top = 0;
    rect.bottom = 100;
    rect.left = 0;
    rect.right = 100;
    CString s = L"This is a very very long text that should span accross multiple lines and have elipsis at the end";
    dc.DrawText(s, &rect, DT_EDITCONTROL | DT_WORDBREAK | DT_END_ELLIPSIS);
}
```